# Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP) strategy/ implementation for AEM

Tags: mobile, aem, amp-html

What is the best approach/ strategy to implementing Accelerated Mobile Pages (https://www.ampproject.org/) within AEM 6.1 for a responsive web site that already renders for both desktop and mobile?

An initial concern is that you would be creating duplicate pages of content.  So is it possible that AMP and normal html can share the same content?
Would you always redirect to AMP if mobile, and what is the best way to do that?
How would an author handle both AMP and standard pages?

Answer (score 3):

More information is required to completely answer your question -

- What is your approach towards responsive design (if you are supporting desktop)? Are mobile site and desktop site different?
- What version of AEM are you using?

> How would an author handle both AMP and standard pages?

Authoring is something which is not AMP specific, AMP is a feature/behavior that you would enforce on Publish instance and not Author. But this depends on your approach towards responsive behavior - single site handing both mobile and desktop or separate?

a) If there are separate sites then you would actually cater to AMP behavior on author as well by having different components/resource types and page templates for it (This is how prior to AEM 5.6 mobile sites were handled). ***I can provide more details if you are following this approach***

b) If there is single site then you should configure this at publish only.

> is it possible that AMP and normal html can share the same content?

In short Yes, depends on how you design your components and/or what version of AEM are you using. In AEM 6.2, Adobe has introduced [content fragments](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/author/page-authoring/content-fragments.html) that allows channel agnostic content management i.e. more like assets.

If you are not using AEM 6.2, even then you can allow for reusable content by designing for it. You could create a global space with content pieces and then use reference component to associate/use that content on different pages (the only challenge with this is to manage full text search if you have that on your site).

> Would you always redirect to AMP if mobile, and what is the best way
>   to do that?

What ever approach you take a) or b) (as described in first answer), the essence for managing the redirects/rewrites is to exploit user-agent information in request. Apache/httpd allows to handle user-agent information and do a redirect of rewrite.

For approach a) you will redirect to your mobile site after identifying that user-agent is mobile user-agent and for approach b) you could rewrite the url (not redirect) add a selector that allows for you AMP specific resource scripts to render the content. ***Selector based solution is one possible way of implementing the single site for both web and AMP***

**UPDATE:**

Assuming that you need to cache both AMP version and normal HTML markup, the solution is to use a special selector for rendering AMP version of markup. You could setup a component hierarchy -

Lets say your base page structure is abstracted out in a custom component called - `AbstractPageComponent` (this in most cases is replica of foundation/components/page customized to project need) and all your page components extend this component. What you could do is create another such component lets say `AMPAbstractPageComponent`, setup this page structure similar to standard Abstract component i.e. let it have its own copy of scripts head,body,content, header,footer etc. But make sure you name them differently from the convention in `AbstractPageComponent`, u could do that by pre-pending amp to them like amp-head.html, aem-body.html,amp-content.html. Then there will be AMPAbstractPageComponent.html the component rendering script that structures the page by including relevant AMP scripts and/or `AbstractPageComponent` scripts.

Each of these scripts should have the AMP specific logic and where-ever you need to refer to HTML logic include/defer to the `AbstractPageComponent`'s script.

Now define the selector script to ensure AMP specific rendition, let say your selector is `amp` then in `AbstractPageComponent` create a `amp.html` or `amp.jsp` and in this script include `AMPAbstractPageComponent.html`

**NOTE**: The ideal structure to implement will be `foundation Page` -> `AbstractPageComponent` -> `AMPAbstractPageComponent` -> `Other page templates`

I have specified `AMPAbstractPageComponent` to be parent of `AbstractPageComponent` assuming that your site already exists and there is content pages referring to existing structure. If your site structure permits you to introduce `AMPAbstractPageComponent` between `AbstractPageComponent` -> `Other page templates` then you should do that and let `AMPAbstractPageComponent` handle that `amp` selector.

What i have defined above is the first level of change, next you need to consider the components inclusion that have AMP specific handling. For components included in templates you need pass on the selector `amp` if its coming in the URL otherwise included component will render their default script (component included in the templates not drag and dropped components).Dragged and dropped components will automatically try to render `amp` script if available and in case its not then default to its own script.

---

**Please note, this is approach based on the selector resolution, for actual implementation to do AMP specific work you may have to do other stuff as well, another thing i have not included is the managing component rendering i.e if you normal html includes a parsys and that script in not included in your AMP implementation your components will not render. So you will either have to duplicate those inclusions in AMP specific scripts or you will have to include the AbstractComponent's scripts to include such components**

Do a small PoC, I gave the approach solely based on high level understanding of what AMP does by reading the link you have specified.

Comment: Have updated the question, AEM 6.1 and an existing responsive website for both desktop and mobile.

Comment: @enkor - Were you able to figure out how to get AMP rollin on AEM site?

Comment: Hey I really like your answer here. You describe the options quiet good. I think I will go with the selector in the first place while trying out AMP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually thinking about implementing the same and here is the thought path laid out so far (untested):

- add new page extension handler at foundation/components/primary/cq/page (overlay it under /apps) named Page.amp.jsp with `<%@include file="proxy.jsp" %>` content
- add page renderer into your application logic at the same place where are you rendering html pages

The rest should be done by ootb [sling URL resolution handler](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html)